# Ethernet installation in New house using Legrand TM1110 Terminal Telephone Input Module

Tags: networking, ethernet

I recently moved to a new house and it is pre wired with ethernet. Today, I finally decided to check out the wiring in order to connect an additional Wireless Access point in a different room. My Internet router provided by my ISP has a built in switch with about 6 additional ports so I decided to connect an Ethernet cable from one of the ports to the Ethernet Jack on the wall thinking I would be able to get the signal in any other jack in the house, unfortunately that was not the case.

So I bought a tone tracer and determined the cable is not actually connected to anything (see picture below with circled unpatched cable).

[image: unpatched cable]

So, my question is, in order to Provide Ethernet Access with Internet to the rest of the house, do I have to patch this cable to the Legran TM1110 terminal Service In slot?

[image: Legrand Terminal]

Will this actually work? I also see there is an Ethernet Jack in this Legrand Terminal, what's that for? Can I terminate the cable with an Ethernet jack and plug it there.

In any case, what's the best solution? Last resort I can also always install an actual switch in there since there is a power outlet, and terminate all the cable with jacks but I suspect there must be a better solution.

Comment: The connections look as if they were done by an electrician instead of a network technician: too much of the UTP cable is unsheathed and untwisted.  Have you even identified what category number that cable is?

Comment: I have not identified what Category number it is, but I believe it's Cat 5. I'll check that out.

Comment: As a follow up to this question, I ended up buying a cheap non managed switch. Yanked all the ethernet cables from the Legrand TM, terminated them with Ethernet Jacks and plugged them into the switch which I left inside the panel since there is a power outlet. It has been working fine for over a year now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it using this box. Looking at [https://www.amazon.com/Q-Telecom-Modules-Module-Connections/dp/B00F5CJJOQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00F5CJJOQ) and other resources this Legrand box appears to be for telephones (only), bridging the input across all outputs.

As Ethernet is point-to-point you should replace this with something that will let you take advantage if point-to-point wiring.  I would likely rip out the Legrand nonsense and replace it with something providing 10 x RJ45 sockets and then punch down the existing wiring in to those.  I would then add a switch on the other side.

I do note that it is technically possible to crimp the cables and feed them directly into a switch, but be careful as you are likely dealing with solid core (in-wall/structured cable), while most cables are stranded core.  This can cause some difficulties and performance loss if not done right.

Comment: Thank you for that insight @davidgo . I might try adding a small switch inside that panel and see how that works, if it's a no go I will do what you mention. Cheers!