# RJ45 Terminations for Legrand TM1110

Tags: networking, ethernet

This questions is stimulated by this other question:

- [Ethernet installation in New house using Legrand TM1110 Terminal Telephone Input Module](https://superuser.com/questions/1585252/ethernet-installation-in-new-house-using-legrand-tm1110-terminal-telephone-input/1821978)

My house also has the
Legrand TM1110. The "service in" wires terminate to a traditional male phone jack. The eight vertical ports are wired, leading to both phone jacks and RJ45 jacks.

In this scenario, if I terminate the "service in" wire with an RJ45, could I plug that into the back of a cable modem and have internet service at the RJ45s? i.e., would the wires deliver the signal, no?

Comment: Short answer, no.

Answer (score 4):

No. Ethernet wiring rules are far, FAR more strict than telephone wiring.

If you have Cat5 or better cables terminating in your TM1110, and you don't need them for analog landline telephone service any more, you should disconnect them from the TM1110 and punch them down to the back of a patch panel (a row of female RJ-45s). Then install an Ethernet switch next to that patch panel and use short patch cables to connect from the patch panel to switch ports.

This assumes that the blue-jacketed cables in your picture are all "home runs", meaning that they each go directly from a single wall jack down to this wiring panel. If any of them have any splitters or splices or taps or daisy chaining, they won't work for Ethernet. Ethernet requires home runs. It is intolerant of a lot of things you could get away with, with analog landline telephone wiring.

If you have a DOCSIS cable modem, if it's truly *just* a modem (that is, if it doesn't create a Wi-Fi network or have 3-4 LAN ports or do NAT or act as a DHCP server), then you'll need a router. Connect an Ethernet cable from the modem's Ethernet port to the WAN port of the router. Then connect an Ethernet cable from a LAN port of the router to any port on the switch, and you've got a great home network. If the DOCSIS device you have is actually a DOCSIS gateway/router and not just a DOCSIS modem, then you can just plug an Ethernet cable from one of the LAN ports of your DOCSIS gateway to the switch. In fact, if your router already has 3-4 LAN ports like most do, and you don't need any more switch ports than that, you could just patch directly from the patch panel to the router LAN ports without an Ethernet switch.

Comment: Even if it's cat3 I'd try it for gigabit. It's likely to work. I've been running 50m GbE links on CAT3...